# How involved (crazy) is it to lift my Pontiac a couple of inches?

Tags: suspension, lift-kit

I'm a pretty experienced DIY-er, but I'm not familiar with the process for lifting a car. How involved is the process for just 2-3 inches, and can it be done for a vehicle that doesn't necessarily have a lift "kit" available? A 2006 Pontiac G6 GT (sedan), in my case.

Comment: That's actually a pretty fun google image search: [lifted+pontiac](https://www.google.com/search?q=lifted+pontiac&tbm=isch).  But seriously... _Why_ do you want to lift it?  The approach could vary depending on what you expect to get out of it.

Comment: I want to add more rubber between the rim and the road. I currently have the smallest rims that my brake calipers will accommodate (18"?), and the largest tires that will fit in my wheel-well, and there's still only about 4 inches between the rim and the street. Low-profile wheels are sporty and all, but they're also very easy to bend, and they produce more road noise in an already noisy car. I'd like to keep the brakes if I can, so if I can lift instead of getting smaller rims, that'd be nice.

Comment: LOL!! I'm not looking for anything that extreme. Just something like the Honda Crosstour.

Comment: Any other answers? As popular as this seems to be for style reasons, it's surprisingly difficult to find good information about it...

Comment: It bothers me that there isn't an answer to this.